# Google sheets convert time to decimal

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I've got an issue with some time data that is exported from a program like this into cells (each number with text in each cell descending all in column a)

0h

14h

17h

17h

25h 30m

0h

8h 30m

7h

I need to somehow have this converted in to decimal time 25.5 the main problem is that it has text it the cells (h and m) which I cant remove to even start converting it. Any ideas the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

to solve even the cases with spaced m and h, such as those in the attached image, you could try this other calculation:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A2:A="","",iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"(\d+\s?)h"),"") + iferror(Round(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"(\d+\s?)m")/60,2),"")))
```

Comment: amazing, it worked, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

you can try for not integer:

```
=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(A11; "(.+)+h ?(.+)m"; ("$2")))/60 + VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(A11; "(.+)h ?(.+)?m?"; ("$1")))
```

and for integer:

```
=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(A9; "(.+)h ?(.+)?m?"; ("$1")))
```

I cant get that together

Comment: I've got something similar to this using this =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("m",Q3)),SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Q3,"h ",":"),"m",":0"),SUBSTITUTE(Q3, "h",":0:0"))*24 now however i dont know how to make array if you know. Thanks for commenting and helping me

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your Col-A data begins in A2 (with a header, say, in A1).

Make sure Col-B is empty (or some other column) and then place the following formula in cell B1 (or the top cell of some other open column):

`=ArrayFormula({"Converted"; IF(A2:A="",, REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"\d+") + REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A&"0m","(\d+)m")/60)})`

This one formula will created the header (which you can change as you like within the formula itself) and all conversions for non-null cells in Col A.

Comment: Thanks Erik, I've used your formula however it seems to miss out the minute side of things so 25h 30m formats to 25 instead of 25.5

I have managed to get this working however its not in an array format which would be preferable =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("m",Q3)),SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Q3,"h ",":"),"m",":0"),SUBSTITUTE(Q3, "h",":0:0"))*24

Comment: My formula works fine in my own sheet with your data. It's likely that you just had the results range set to the wrong format (such as *0*) instead of *0.00*. If you'd like to share a link to a sample spreadsheet, I can take a look. But as I say, the formula I provided worked to produce all expected results in my own sheet.